# How to fix Failed to load the native Tensorflow runtime on Conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll, anaconda, conda

I installed all the packages and conda itself using this link [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s730/client/snv?noteGuid=f60a69be-cb67-45f7-8054-c71035478b5e&noteKey=5d7ca2a094dd33a599ef57715403cead&sn=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.evernote.com%2Fshard%2Fs730%2Fsh%2Ff60a69be-cb67-45f7-8054-c71035478b5e%2F5d7ca2a094dd33a599ef57715403cead&title=Installation%2Bguide%2Bfor%2BDeepometry) (all the instructions I followed for installation is in the link)

Visual Code was installed along with Java SE Dev Kit 11 as per instructions and all the dependencies were installed exactly. However, I am getting an error regarding 1 or 2 missing DLL's when checking out the GUI branch in the link above and running python deepometry_GUI.py. As a reminder, this is all within a Conda env

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Deepometry_GUI.py", line 20, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Rafay Osmani\.conda\envs\Deepometry\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

It seems that all I need to do is install the missing DLL's and I am on my way. The problem is that the error message is ambiguous
and I do not know what DLL's I need to install. Would be appreciated if I could be let known how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Get the path of your conda environment by executing below command.

```
import os
os.environ['PATH']
```

Then add the obtained path under your system path, this should work.